# OVH Domain & Let's encrypt SSL validation failure

Tags: lets-encrypt, ovh

I followed all the instructions to get a SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt  for my website, but two hours after I successfully got the message "Your certificate and chain have been saved", I still cannot access my website with HTTPS and get the error "the website refused the connection".

Do you know how much time is needed to activate the certificate?

Comment: Can you provide a domain name to help debugging? If you need direct assistance from OVH staff, I'd recommend joining the "web" maillinglist (send a mail to web-subscribe@ml.ovh.net to subscribe)

Answer (score 2):

On the web hosting offer of OVH, the HTTPS protocol is available after the deployment on all the load balancing infrastructure. It take around two hours.

You can check your "multisite". Maybe your website doesn't have the "SSL" flag enabled and the generated certificate do not handle your website.